# Are URLs with multiple periods in the URL path valid?

Tags: url, web, standards

I would like to know whether below URLs are valid or not.

Dots in the path, after the host:

`http://www.example.com/v.b.w..com`

Dots in the host, as part of the sub-domain:

`http://v.b.w..co.manufacturer.example.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **`..` in the path is valid** (`example.com/v.b.w..com`):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) allows it, and even lists it in its [abnormal examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.4.2):

```
Within a representation with a well defined base URI of
    http://a/b/c/d;p?q
a relative reference is transformed to its target URI as follows.
⋮
"g.."           =  "http://a/b/c/g.."
"..g"           =  "http://a/b/c/..g"
```

Note that `/../` will not be valid, because the URL would be interpreted to have a relative part - a link to `a/b/../c` is like a link to `a/c`.

2. **`..` in the sub-domain is invalid** (`http://no..bad.example.com`):

From [RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), section 5, *BNF for specific URL schemes*:

```
host           = hostname | hostnumber
hostname       = *[ domainlabel "." ] toplabel
domainlabel    = alphadigit | alphadigit *[ alphadigit | "-" ] alphadigit
```

Only a single period is permitted between tokens.

Answer (score 1):

nslookup will tell you if it's not a legal name.

I ran the following on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

```
$ nslookup http://v.b.w..co.manufacturer.domain.com/
nslookup: 'http://v.b.w..co.manufacturer.domain.com/' is not a legal name (empty label)
```